# get value out of encapsulated json

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I've the following JSON file:

```
[

{
    "AVG_VALUE" : "2540", 
    "MAX_VALUE" : "2540",
    "SUM_VALUE" : "2540",
    "MIN_VALUE" : "2540",
    "METRICID" : "100248060212",
    "START" : "1449216120000",
    "STARTTIME" : "09:02"
}
,
{
    "AVG_VALUE" : "2624", 
    "MAX_VALUE" : "2708",
    "SUM_VALUE" : "5248",
    "MIN_VALUE" : "2540",
    "METRICID" : "100248060219",
    "START" : "1449216120000",
    "STARTTIME" : "09:02"
}
]
```

But I don't know how to get the values out of it? I'm using the dojo toolkit and I'm generating my file with this code:

```
var stream = dojo.xhrGet({
            url : self.jsonFile,
            content : {
                startTime : 1449136661084,
                endTime :   1449482261084,
                interValMillis : (interval * 1000),
                metricid : 100248060219
            },
            handleAs : "json",
            sync : true,
            load : function(response, ioArgs) {
                self.data = response;
                self._metricIds = _metricIds;
                self._params = _params;
                self.convertData(self);
                console.log("ok:"+response);
                data = response;
            }
        });
```

So at the end all the values are now in my response var... but how can I adress it, to get i.e the first AVG_VALUE?

Comment: It's an array: `data[0].AVG_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON data is stored in object arrays, thus you will need to loop through them to get to the values contained inside..

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
var jsonData = response[i];
jsonData['AVG_VALUE'] 
}
```

The above will return all values which correspond to the variable AVG_VALUE - alternatively if you only want the first one then you can use:

```
 var jsonData = response;
jsonData[0]['AVG_VALUE']
```

Answer (score 0):

Response is an object array. You can adress it like `response[0]['AVG_VALUE']` or like `response[0].AVG_VALUE`.